# Simple C Program ABACADABRA

Tags: c

Please Help!! I am having some difficulty completing this assignment for the course that I am taking. [Link to Assignment](http://cseweb.ucsd.edu/classes/wi18/ece15-a/Labs/lab2.pdf) It is problem 3 in this pdf. All I'm trying to do is compare one array to another array to make sure that every letter in my "word" array matches one of the letters in my "natural" array (that has the ABRACADABRA alphabet in it). I haven't even started on the encryption part yet, but I think I have the algorithm worked out for that. So far I have:

```
int main()
{
    int i = 0, w = 0, j = 0;
    char nat[5] = { 'a','b','c','d','r' };
    char in[5], inw[7];

    printf("Enter key:  ");

    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        in[i] = getchar();
    }

    printf("Enter word: ");

    for (w = 0; w < 7; w++)
    {
        inw[w] = getchar();
    }

    while (j < 5)
    {
        while (inw[w] != nat[j])
        {
            j++;
        }
        if (inw[w] == nat[j])
        {
            w++;
            j = 0;
        }
    }

    if (j == 5)
    {
        printf("You did not speak ABRACADABRA to me!\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Don't add a "Link to assignment". Your question is supposed to contain all relevant information.

Comment: What are you doing with the `'\n'` character placed in `stdin` by pressing the [Enter] key?

Answer (score 3):

Your code can be simplified greatly, while improving how it works.

The loops that `getchar()` will fail if given less input; you should just use `sscanf()` with a size-limited string conversion, or [`getline()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/getline) if you have it.

You should make the alphabet a proper string:

```
const char *nat = "abcdr";
```

and then use [`strchr()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strchr) to search a string for a character, passing `nat` as  the string.

Comment: @Jonathan `fgets` might also be useful.